# How operate on TFileStream

Tags: delphi, pascal

Hello recently I replace `TextFile` with `TFileStream`. I never use it so I have small problem with it.

- How can I add someting to my file after I assign it to variable?
- How can I read someting form that file?

I need defined line form that file so I was doing something like that:

```
var linia_klienta:array[0..30] of string;
AssignFile(tempPlik,'klienci.txt');
Reset(tempPlik);
i:=0;
While Not Eof(tempPlik) do
  begin
    Readln(tempPlik,linia_klient[i]);
    inc(i);
  end;
CloseFile(tempPlik);
```

Then when line two is needed I simply

```
edit1.text = linia_klienta[1];
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you need to read a text file and access each line, try instead using a [TStringList](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TStringList) class with this class you can  load a file, read the data (accesing each line using a index) and save the data back.

something like this

```
FText  : TStringList;
i : integer;
begin
 FText := TStringList.Create;
 try
  FText.LoadFromFile('C:\Foo\Foo.txt');

    //read the lines
    for i:=0 to FText.Count-1 do    
     ProcessLine(FText[i]);  //do something   

  //Add additional lines
  FText.Add('Adding a new line to the end');
  FText.Add('Adding a new line to the end');    

  //Save the data back
  FText.SaveToFile('C:\Foo\Foo.txt');

 finally
  FText.Free;
 end;

end;

end;
```

Comment: That looks nice... wait for it. Can I create new file?

Comment: Using TStrings is very memory-inefficient.

Comment: @Dudi, yes only get rid the line `loadfromfile` and then add new lines.

Comment: @user539484 `TStringList` is not bad for normal text files size. In the OP question, it states `[0..30] of string` which is pretty nothing. In this case, `TStringList` is just efficient and easy to use.

Comment: @PRUZ Sorry but it is not perfectly clear for me. When I want create new file how it look like?

Comment: @Dudi: SaveToFile creates a new file, if it does not yet exist.

Comment: But why when use 'SaveToFile' it overwrite exist content?

Comment: @PRUZ there is any chace to save exist content?

Comment: Are you trying of append data to this file? btw is `RRUZ` not `PRUZ`.

Comment: @Arnaud Bouchez, you have to define "normal" text file size first :-) BTW, OP reads to EOF, so N of lines might be more that just 31 (X < 62G-31 bytes)

Comment: @Dudi, yes use the `delete` method passing the index of the line to remove `FText.Delete(Index);` btw if you have any addional question about this class fell free to ask(start) a new question in S.O.

Comment: I know I should but i figure that out quickly with [this](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList)

Answer (score 6):

I newer versions of Delphi you can use [TStreamReader](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TStreamReader) / [TStreamWriter](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Classes.TStreamWriter) here is an example of using TStreamReader ... this is only for manipulating text files

```
var
  SR : TStreamReader;
  line : String;
begin
  SR := TStreamReader.Create('D:\test.txt');
  while not (SR.EndOfStream) do
  begin
    line := SR.ReadLine;
    ShowMessage(line);
  end;
  SR.Free;
 end;
```

Answer (score 1):

TStream and its immediate descendants are mostly low-level access class. They mostly deal with generic buffers. There are some more specialized classes that descend from or use a stream to perform higher level tasks.

Since Delphi 1 TReader and TWriter could be used to read and write Delphi types directly (inlcuding strings), but they were not designed to handle "line-oriented" files (unluckily they were designed too much with component properties streaming in mind, not as a general purpose framework).

[Turbo Power SysTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/) has a nice TStAnsiTextStream class that implements line-oriented access to text files in a way similar to that of TextFile. Since Delphi 2009 new classes (see opc0de answer) implement the same kind of access without the need of third party libraries (moreover they support different encodings thanks to Delphi 2009 extend codepage support, including Unicode).

Answer (score 0):

Depending with what you want to do, its the stream class you need.

Do you want to work with text (characters with break-lines and end-of-line characters) data ?

OR, do you want to work with binary data ?

I see you are using an array of char, instead, of a string.
Do you really want to use character data as if it was binary ?
Sometimes, some applications require that case.

Comment: I'm using array of string.
I need create new file/load from file, add new content to file.

Comment: I also suggest to use the TStringList class to manage several lines instead on a plain array. The problem here is how to read / write all those lines with a text / edit / memo control. The previous TStringList example already shows that.